# Angular ui-router ng-if current exact state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, parent-child, nested-routes

Having trouble managing my parent-child state mostly as I am new to ui-router. However, I've done research and came across solutions that require hard-coding of routes but are not dynamic.

What I currently have:

```
<div> <!-- parent state -->
    <div ng-if="'.' | isState">
        <!-- 
          background hierarchy that should be visible only when
          parent state is active and not a child state of the parent
        -->
    </div>
    <nav>
        <a ui-sref="." ui-sref-active="active">Parent</a>
        <a ui-sref=".child1" ui-sref-active="active">Child 1</a>
        <a ui-sref=".child2" ui-sref-active="active">Child 2</a>
    </nav>
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to accomplish?
When the parent loads, I want the background to show something. It takes up the whole screen. The `ui-view` will not take up the whole screen. As such, I want background element to be hidden or removed when route does not exactly match the parent's state (if parent's route is `/root/parent`, I want background to be visible only when state is exactly `/root/parent` and not `/root/parent/child1`).

I am able to achieve what I want only when I provide the exact expected route. For example `ng-if="'root.parent' | isState"`.

Also, `ui-sref-active="active"` retains `active` class when children views are shown (it is expected but I want the class only to be active when the route matches exactly).

However, I do not feel that it is good to hard-code route of the parent into view. I just want it to match whatever route it belongs to. As such, if I later decide to move it to `/root/parent/car`, I shouldn't have to update `ng-if` and `ui-sref-active` to reflect the change.

Has anyone ran into the issue and was able to resolve it?

Comment: What is the reason for you having the parent-child hierarchy ?

Comment: remove `active` class from child routes `<a ui-sref=".child1">Child 1</a>` and add `css` to `active` class so that it only appears in background.

Comment: @arqam The main content of the page is actually displayed as a background and the children contain optional content that can be hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the replies but one of the conditions in a solution I was seeking was to try and avoid hard-coding a state. My solution is as follows:

For the nav links, I had to read the ui-router directive code to find `ui-sref-active-eq` directive, which I applied in the following way:

```
<nav>
    <a ui-sref="." ui-sref-active-eq="active">Parent</a>
    <a ui-sref=".child1" ui-sref-active="active">Child 1</a>
    <a ui-sref=".child2" ui-sref-active="active">Child 2</a>
</nav>
```

The directive ensure that `Parent` link is active only when the URL is exactly equal to the parent's URL.

As for the showing/hiding the background, I have the following code. Again, note that in neither case do I hard-code a state name:

```
function ParentController ($scope, $state, $stateParams, $q) {
    var model = this;
    var controllerState = $state.current.name;

    $scope.showBackground = true;

    $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', onStateChange);

    init();

    function init () {
        onStateChange();
    }

    function onStateChange() {
        $scope.showBackground = $state.is(controllerState);
    }
}
```

And then in the View:

```
<div ng-if="showBackground">
    <!-- 
      background hierarchy that should be visible only when
      parent state is active and not a child state of the parent
    -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `$state.current.name` for your condition

```
<div ng-if="$state.current.name === 'state1'">

</div>
```

Comment: Make sure you do not put state name in quotes. like  `ng-if="$state.current.name === 'state1'"` , it should be like `ng-if="$state.current.name === state1"`

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished in few ways, as you might have a `parentController` separate.

You can check the state in controller and prevent it in view using `ng-if`

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$state) {
     if($state.current.name == 'your parentstate')
        {
          $scope.stateName = true;
        }
     else
        {
          $scope.stateName = false;
        }

});
```

**View:**

```
<div ng-if="stateName">
  // this only executes if current stateName is parent state
</div>
```

**The above only executes if current stateName is parent state**

Or,

You can simply remove `active class` from child routes,

```
 <a ui-sref=".child1">Child 1</a> 
 <a ui-sref=".child2">Child 2</a>
```

**Now, add CSS to active class so that it only appears in background for parent.**

Comment: @DraganTL, please check my answer.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't address one part in OP, where I do not want to hard-code a state (self or parent). I have resolved the issue just now and will post my solution.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is checking the state in the controller and do what you need to do

```
app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
    if ($state.is('my-active-state')) {
        // do stuff when the state is active
    } else {
        // do stuff when the state is NOT active
    }
});
```

Check the [Docs](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/0.3.1/index.html#/api/ui.router.state.$state#methods_is) for more info.